# JavaFX 2 Creating a Custom Pane

Tags: layout, javafx-2

I have seen several custom JavaFX control tutorials around, but no tutorials on how to create a custom pane layout. I ask because I am trying to create a flowing two-sided (think form-like (name,value) pairs) layout pane with titles. I have previously done the control in WPF, and am "migrating" it to JavaFX. Are there any places I could look for learning how to make a custom layout pane aside from the OpenJDK sources?

To clarify: I an looking for how to create a custom pane *layout manager* and not custom *controls*

Comment: Maybe you should look at miglayout. It is a port of a famous Swing layout in JavaFX, you can check the sources to see how they made it. http://www.miglayout.com/

Comment: Are you trying to create a layout pane (e.g. [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) subclass) or a control (e.g. [Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html) subclass)?  Why can't you just use a [GridPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)?  Can you add a screen shot of the [WPF rendered pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html) in your question?  Can you provide a link to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) containing the existing WPF code?

Comment: Pane subclass. [WPF Code](https://bitbucket.org/byteit101/zomb-dashboard-system/src/8478ccd714a041c3ce22a914f9bf2e31074fff4e/ZomBdll/WPF/Controls/FlowPropertyGrid.cs?at=default) and [Screenshot](http://firstforge.wpi.edu/sf/go/page1035) (in the bottom right of first photo, with the "ZomB", "Appearance", "Misc", etc.. headers). I can't use a grid pane because resizing must reflow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure myself, but I think you should override `layoutChildren` method from the `Parent` class. This method is called each time the JavaFX performs layout pass.

You may use [controlsfx project](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/overview) code as sample. Just clone it and search for `layoutChildren` string in the project. impl.org.controlsfx.spreadsheet.GridRowSkin.java looks like a good example.

Comment: Yes, layoutChildren + layoutInArea worked for me. JRuby source of my solution: https://bitbucket.org/byteit101/sfx/src/f5f5199e/lib/utils/titled_form_pane.rb?at=default#cl-49

Answer (score 0):

I hope the TableView in JavaFX will serve your requirement of creating a form like structure. Ideally you should go for custom layouts only when no existing layouts serve your purpose. Here is the link to learn more about creating custom layouts:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html

Answer (score -2):

you can use [Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html)...this is specially made for make all types of custom controls and designing in javafx.

Comment: No, that is not what I asked or clarified in the above comments. I am making a layout manager, *not* a custom control. I've found lots of tutorials on custom controls, and use Scene Builder, but nothing for layout managers.